# the definite article with inventions

Tags: articles

Do we always use the definite article with *inventions*?

1. The paper and the gunpowder were invented in China. (an example from my student's book).
2. Paper and gunpowder were invented in China. (I've seen this sentence in quite a few British and American scientific articles).

Thank you!

Comment: Dan, perhaps you mean the INdefinite article...

Comment: That's not true.  We use definite articles with uncountable nouns all the time.  "The music of Beethoven was beautiful."  Music is an accountable noun.  "The paper used in newspapers is often recycled."  In this example, paper is being used as an uncountable noun and properly has a definite article before it.

Comment: Uncountable nouns do not ordinarily take an article, definite or indefinite.  Both of your examples @BenjaminHarman are qualified in a way that makes them countable - the *music of Beethoven* (as opposed to the *music of Schubert*), the *paper used in newspapers* as opposed to the *paper used  in books*.  In both instances I would much more naturally say Beethoven's music, book paper, newspaper paper ...

Comment: @Dan: First, I didn't say anything about what uncountable nouns "ordinarily" do.  Second, the question isn't about countable or uncountable nouns. It's about whether or not one can use the definite article "the" with paper and gunpowder. Third, as I clearly explained, we can use a definite article with uncountable nouns. Doing so causes a shift in meaning, which was EXACTLY my point and THE point, while your ongoing diatribe about "uncountable" vs. "countable" is BESIDE the point. Fourth, giving me a downvote doesn't somehow make you right, just a bit of a jerk while still being wrong.

Comment: @choster has provided an exceptional example of uncountable nouns being listed with 'the' (below).  This is an exceptional case.

Comment: I suggest you not trust that "student's book".

Answer (score 3):

***If an invention is countable*** (e.g computers) then you can choose to say either

*"Computers were invented..." or "The computer was invented...".*

**If an invention is uncountable** (e.g. gunpowder) then the definite article is not usually used.

*"Gunpowder was invented in China;"*

*"Morphine is poisonous"*:

"*Sugar is sweet"*;

*"Paper is useful"*.

When uncountable inventions are listed with the definite article - *the paper, the gunpowder, the morphine* ... - this is usually because the simple uncountable noun has been qualified (either explicitly or elliptically) and made into a countable compound noun -

the paper-*we-are-using...* ;

the gunpowder-*made-in-England...* ;

the sugar-*on-the-shelf...* ;

the music-*we-are-talking-about* ;

the morphine-*in-the-shop...* .

This post is helpful https://english.stackexchange.com/a/198867/103961

Answer (score 0):

We sometimes use the with singular countable nouns to talk in general about inventions and technology. This is optional and we often prefer to use ‘no article’ plus a plural or uncountable noun instead:

> **The** wheel was probably invented around 10,000 years ago.
>
> I think **the** computer has caused the biggest change recently in how we
>   work.

Beckwith, S. (2013). 'A' and 'The' explained: A learner's guide to definite and indefinite articles (p. 40).

[http://www.amazon.com/The-Explained-learners-definite-indefinite/dp/1494245884](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1494245884)

Comment: Both wheels and computers are countable.  Both OP examples are  uncountable nouns.

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that both options are possible. The question was: "Do we always use the definite article with inventions?" It's optional, as I've noted it in the second sentence of my answer.

Comment: You're right. Mea culpa. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198834/about-the-definite-and-zero-article-meaning-generic-concepts

Answer (score -1):

The word *inventions* isn't the deciding factor.  What you are trying to say is.

> The paper and the gunpowder were invented in China.

In the above, *the* works adjectivally to tell the reader that specifically that paper and that gunpowder being referred to in context was invented in China.  For example, if I were working with fireworks and a child asked me where fireworks were invented, I might say, "Well, the paper and the gunpowder were invented in China."

> Paper and gunpowder were invented in China.

Here you are talking generally.  You are saying the product that we all know of as paper and the product we all know of as gunpowder were invented in China.

Comment: *"**The** paper and **the** gunpowder were invented in China."*  Really?!

Comment: @Dan All you need is a reference *paper* and a reference *gunpowder*. "Imagine a basket of commodities. The paper and the gunpowder were invented in China, the morphine in Germany; and the muslin in Bangladesh."

Comment: @choster - thanks, very helpful.  But... isn't your sentence an exception.  Except when listing where items were invented, doesn't a definite article with an uncountable noun always involve an ellipsis (the paper *we are using*, the gunpowder *in that box*, the morphine *in the shop*) which changes the simple uncountable noun into a countable compound noun? The OP asks if the definite article is always used with inventions.  If the invention is uncountable the simple answer is that 'the' is not used. *Gunpowder* was invented in China. The *gunpowder here* was made in England.

Comment: @Dan That's what I mean by a reference *paper*. The OP hasn't actually given us any context, so we don't know whether *the* is appropriate or not here, but it's not right to say it's always wrong.

Comment: Memo to self - "Never say 'never' or 'always':  'Almost always', 'usually', ordinarily'...".  Thanks.  I've deleted my excessive assertion!

Comment: @Dan: It's good to see a man admit when he's wrong.  Incidentally, you should also know that uncountable nouns can remain uncountable even with "the."  For example, one could say, "The music of Bach and Beethoven was revolutionary unto the world of music, Bach unto the Baroque and Beethoven unto the Classical."  One would not say, "The musics of Bach and Beethoven were revolutionary."  Moreover, simply saying, "the music of Beethoven" with a "the" in front is clearly uncountable, referring not just to his "kind" of music but to his many pieces of music, which is how uncountable nouns operate.

Comment: I work for the department of languages and linguistics of a university teaching English to ESL students preparing fore the TOEFL exam.  I also speak two foreign languages myself fluently.  I'm well aware of the needs of ESL students.  I'm also aware that user146059 is not an ESL student.  That much becomes abundantly clear simply from reading user146059's posts.  So, that being the case, we need to take this question at face value and not read into it with inferences that user146059's never implied.