# the + noun describing a person to imply a generic concept

Tags: definite-articles, generic

I am writing documentation for an online store platform. Can I use a construction like "the customer" in a generic sense, when it is supposed to mean "any customer of any online store that uses the platform". Or shall I start with "a customer" in every help article and then go with "the customer" only when the word appears for the second time?

Based on this article [About the definite and zero article meaning generic concepts](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198834/about-the-definite-and-zero-article-meaning-generic-concepts) I guess the use of "the" in this sense is limited to species and inventions but I'd like to make sure nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

We would need the exact context to determine which identifier is correct, but generally, there is nothing wrong with using "the customer" in this sort of writing.

In documentation for a website, "the customer" would be understood to mean *the customer who is using this application*.