# Does the word "another" correctly substitute for the indefinite article in this sentence?

Tags: articles

I was reading a short story by Ray Bradbury and stumbled on a zero article case in the sentence below.

*"Years passed without another visitor, be it boy, **girl, tramp or travelling man**, knocking at her door."*

I feel that this way it sounds good without an article but I cannot explain why it does.

Comment: While the case works, I'm not sure what your question is. Would this question (and accepted answer) provide an adequate explanation? https://english.stackexchange.com/a/198867/3306

Comment: Thanks for the reaction. To clarify my question, is it correct to explain the absence of an indefinite article ('be it [a] boy, girl...') by the presence of the word *another* in the example. Does it control not only *visitor* (functioning as an article) but other nouns as well... "another... boy, girl...". The link you referred to discusses the definite article usage. I think this case is different. ('be it' is a cool expression, though, does it affect the article usage?)

Comment: Thank you, Greybeard, the comment is illuminating.

Comment: It's archaic language, improperly used by someone who's not archaic enough yet. It should be _be they_, for starts, not _be it_. That's for things and abstractions and qualities, not people.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 5):

The form Bradbury uses is informal and one of the few exceptions to the guidance *"All singular, countable nouns require an article or other determiner."*

It occurs when a list of objects, etc.

(i) is given as general examples, in which case the absence of an article implies  "**any** + singular noun" (as in Bradbury's case)

or

(ii) is repeated in reference to a previous mentioned list, in which case the absence of an article implies "**the previously mentioned**", e.g. *"I was put in charge of the household pets; there was a dog, a cat and a parrot. I left the room for a moment and when I returned, dog, cat, and parrot were chasing each other over all the furniture."*

Obviously, it also occurs where

(iii) the noun is uncountable: *"Sorrow, joy, and anger were all mixed together."*

or

(iv) the noun is the general plural *"We see men, women, and children all clamouring for the same opportunities."*

Actual examples are hard to find as the nouns vary according to context

Comment: Neat answer. A related example may be the usage of *neither fish nor fowl*. See https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/neither+fish+nor+fowl

Comment: I suspect fish and fowl, in that context, are uncountable nouns designating a class of creature.

Answer (score 3):

The (old-fashioned) 'be it ...' construction is discussed at [What does "be it" mean in this passage?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214687/what-does-be-it-mean-in-this-passage)

But this allows the use of articles:

- *His goodwife will be delighted to have a child, be it a boy or a girl.*
- *Nell's cooking tonight; we'll enjoy our food, be it the mutton or the veal.*

The zero article (but not the identical-'looking' null article) can in certain cases replace the indefinite article, and here adds to the olde-worlde effect.

> *Be ye man, Be ye wummin*,
> *Be ye gaun, Be ye cumin*,
> *Be ye early, Be ye late*,
>
> *Dinna furget tae SHUT the GATE.*

[[Google; Hunters Inn](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Be+ye+man%22+-Bibia+-perfect+-whole+-converted+-glad&ei=15FtYLaCGoiG9u8PgqKHwA0&oq=%22Be+ye+man%22+-Bibia+-perfect+-whole+-converted+-glad&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsANQ7XlYrIABYOiOAWgBcAJ4AIABSogBrAKSAQE1mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBBcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwj2yfW0_uvvAhUIg_0HHQLRAdgQ4dUDCA0&uact=5)]
seems to be a related Scots English example (*Be ye [a] man* ...).